# Disable "show live issues" in conditionally compiled code (Swift + Xcode 11)?

Tags: swift, xcode, conditional-compilation

I'm guessing this is a bug of sorts (and if so I'll file a report)...

If you have "show live issues" enabled in Xcode's Preferences, issues can be flagged even in code that won't be compiled because of a conditional compilation block.

Here's a trivial example. When using Xcode 11.5 or earlier the "!!!" causes a syntax error to be flagged even though that code is never compiled:

```
#if swift(>=5.3)
    print("Swift >= 5.3")
    !!! // <-- causes "show live issues" to complain
#else
    print("Swift < 5.3")
#endif
```

Is there any workaround for this that people are aware of?

A "real" example might use syntax that is only available with Swift 5.3+ within the first section and < 5.3 syntax in the second section.

Note that the code will actually compile and run but "show live issues" is getting tripped up by the presence of "invalid" code and ideally it wouldn't check code that won't be compiled.

Note that Objective-C doesn't have this issue, the following doesn't result in any "show live issues" warning if XCODE12 isn't defined:

```
#if defined(XCODE12)
NSLog(@"XCODE12");
!!!
#else
NSLog(@"XCODE11");
#endif
```